# why did asp.net just delete my entire php code directory?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Everything was working just fine and on the last publish my wordpress directory is now gone.

I don't have a folder with the same name in the project/solution. I've been using visual studio for over 2 years but not doing webpages with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you deploy your web site / application on a existing virtual directory, it ask you if you want to delete the existing content in it. I think you missed that check while deploying your application.

Comment: +1. This has hosed more sites than I can tally. ASP like a fresh bowl so it wants to flush the destination before each push.

Comment: it says Existing files in the destination location will be deleted. Continue? So there's no way to set it to not delete other subdirectories? or how should I have this set up?  Previously I clicked Yes since it seems the only way to get it to publish and it did not until this time delete the other subdirectory.